# View more link under badges appears even if there's only one badge left

Tags: bug, user-profiles, user-interface

If you visit [this user's page](https://superuser.com/users/26452/mark-arnott) you'll notice that even if there's only one Badge unlocked by the user, the 'view more' link is shown.

The view more link makes sense if there's many badges but in this case, I don't think the view more link is required.

[image]

Comment: A similar issue occurs with users with very few questions or answers, there's also a "view more" link. For example, consider arulappan's meta profile. "*This user has not answered any questions view more*". Note that the title of that section is also a link to the relevant tab of the user profile, so "view more", while convenient, is redundant and could be removed in cases where the overview contains all data already without loss of functionality.